# move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 2 to be valid path, object given

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.3 to save a file uploaded by a form POST.

This is the code I use in the controller:

```
$fileDir = '/home2/divine/Symfony/src/App/Bundle/Resources/public/files';

$form['my_file']->getData()->move($fileDir, 'book.pdf');
```

Under water, Symfony executes this code to move the file:

```
move_uploaded_file("/tmp/phpBM9kw8", "/home2/divine/Symfony/src/App/Bundle/Resources/public/files/book.pdf");
```

The public directory has 777 permissions.

This is the error I get:

```
"Could not move the file "/tmp/phpBM9kw8" to "/home2/divine/Symfony/src/App/Bundle/Resources/public/files/book.pdf" 

(move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 2 to be valid path, object given)"
```

I'm using PHP 5.3.

**Update:**

This is the code snipped that executes the move_uploaded_file():

```
// Class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile

$target = $this->getTargetFile($directory, $name);

if (!@move_uploaded_file($this->getPathname(), $target)) {

// etc...
```

The $target" variable is created here:

```
protected function getTargetFile($directory, $name = null) {

// Some error handling here...

    $target = $directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.(null === $name ? $this->getBasename() : $this->getName($name));

    return new File($target, false);
}
```

The $target variable is therefor a File class. It does have a __toString() method, inherited from SplFileInfo:

```
/**
 * Returns the path to the file as a string
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.tostring.php
 * @return string the path to the file.
 * @since 5.1.2
 */
public function __toString () {}
```

But somehow that __toString method is not working.

Comment: As it may seem clear to you, one of the parameters is an object, not a string or cannot be converted to string (i.e. the object does not have a __toString() method). By the way, I do hope it's just your dev machine. 777 is a bad idea for live environments...

Comment: Yes, the error indeed says the second parameter is not a string. But I'm confused as to why that is. It definitely seems a string to me.

Comment: `public/files/';` trailing slash needed. Because it's being read as `public/filesbook.pdf';` without it, instead of `public/files/book.pdf';`

Comment: Plus, you also need a valid enctype if you're not already using one.

Comment: I am using enctype="multipart/form-data". Adding the trailing slash didn't help: Symfony already added that if you don't.

Comment: then double check the path and make sure that *all* folders have permissions and not just the one. You may even have to use 755 instead of 777.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But somehow that __toString method is not working

It is one of the “magic methods”, it gets called automatically when the object is used in a string context – so for example if you had `'foo' . $object`.

But I don’t think it is *supposed* to work in this situation here. Because PHP is loosely typed, you can pass *anything* into `move_uploaded_file`. No automatic conversion to string will happen at this point. And then internally, the function only checks if the parameter is a string, but doesn’t try to convert it into one – because that would make little sense, it could be *any* kind of object, and there is no way of telling if calling __toString would result in a valid file path.

---

You might wonder now, why in the error message we do get to see the path:

> Could not move the file "/tmp/phpBM9kw8" to "/home2/divine/Symfony/src/App/Bundle/Resources/public/files/book.pdf"

My guess is, that when that error message is assembled, there is string concatenation going on, so that __toString does get called at this specific point.

---

If you are willing to modify the Symfony source code, I think this should work as an easy fix, if you just change this line

```
if (!@move_uploaded_file($this->getPathname(), $target)) {
```

to

```
if (!@move_uploaded_file($this->getPathname(), ''.$target)) {
```

– then you have the situation again, where __toString will be called, because the object is transferred into a string context by concatenating it with a string (an empty one, because we don’t want to tamper with the resulting value.)

---

Of course modifying a framework’s files directly is not the most recommendable way of dealing with this – after the next update, our change might be lost again. I’d recommend that you check the Symfony bugtracker (they should have something like that) to see if this is a known issue already and if maybe an official patch file exists; and otherwise report it as a bug, so that it can be fixed in a future version.

Comment: Thnx! Indeed, the __toString() method is not automatically called, the concat trick does work. The weird thing is that this code has worked in the past. I'll check the bugtracker.